# How to change the color of overscroll glow on Chrome Android?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll

Is there a way to change the color of the oversroll glow on Chrome Android?

Overscroll glow on Chrome Android:
[image: Overscroll glow on Chrome Android]

[Link to image source](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/overscroll-behavior/#disabling-overscroll-glow-and-rubberbanding-effects)